# HttpListener application closed after handling first request

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, httplistener

```
await main.RunWebHookSubscription();
//

public async Task RunWebHookSubscription()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hook waiting");

            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/hook/");
            listener.Start();
            Task<HttpListenerContext> context = listener.GetContextAsync();
            await HandleRequestAsyncRun(await context);
        }

        async Task HandleRequestAsyncRun(HttpListenerContext context)
        {
            var request = context.Request;
            var body = WebHookRequestHadler(request);
            Console.Write(body);
            var eventData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WebHookEventData>(body);
            //TODO Call method
        }

        string WebHookRequestHadler(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            
            if (!request.HasEntityBody)
            {
                return null;
            }
            using (System.IO.Stream body = request.InputStream) // here we have data
            {
                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(body, request.ContentEncoding))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
```

After handling the first request my application closed. How can I handle requests permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hand off the context to another thread, and then loop back to accept another connection.

You should also dispose the context with `using`, and stop the listener in a `finally`.

```cs
public async Task RunWebHookSubscription()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hook waiting");

    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/hook/");
    listener.Start();
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                using (context.Response)
                    await HandleRequestAsyncRun(context);
            });
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

Consider using `Console.CancelKeyPress` along with a `CancellationTokenSource` to cancel the listener loop.

Comment: I got:
Error CS1674 'HttpListenerContext': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'. HttpListenerExample

Comment: You're right, only the response implements `IDisposable`, not sure why that is